# Why use `git commit` when in a detached state?

Tags: git

Using `git log` I found an old version of my project that I wanted to mess with. I did `git checkout version52` causing the project to be in a '**detached**' state, made some changes, then did `git commit` on it. I didn't realize this would commit in a detached state.

After this I went back to my master with `git checkout master` but when I do `git log` my changes don't show up anymore. I realize now that the changes are stuck in my `version52`.

I can get these changes applied easily enough with `git merge version52` but I was just wondering, what is the point of being able to commit in detached states in git? As a newbie this had me confused for awhile and I don't understand why it's allowed, or when to use such a feature.

EDIT: Sorry, I wrote "disconnected" previously but I meant "detached". In git this happens when you decide to view a previously checked in version of your project.

Comment: this is a question for Super User, no?

Comment: What is a disconnected state - are you referring to a detached HEAD?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant "detached"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the future, you should have created a branch to work off

```
git branch branchName version52
git checkout branchName
```

or

```
git checkout -b brannchName version52
```

**Edited after comment**

The git object model, which I have written about [here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/495049117/git-objects-the-commit), simply tracks a tree of objects. A branch is a pointer to a commit. Although the two are related you don't have to have a branch pointing to the tip of a line of commits.

When you create a commit you are still creating a tree of objects that will exist in the repository until it becomes old and you run git-gc to clean up these orphaned commits. I think what you are worried about is that there is no enforced requirement for commits to be made in a branch. This creates flexibility in the tool that sometimes catches out users, but git is an advanced tool.

In your case you made a commit and then went back to your master branch and you thought you had lost your commits, but if you had looked at the output of `git reflog` you would see the sha of the commit you created even though it wasn't on a branch. You could have created a branch off here by `git branch branchName <sha of commit>`. Or you could have merged or rebased these commits with/onto another branch without going through the extra steps of creating and deleting a branch just for this. Okay, so this is only a couple of extra steps, with only a few keystrokes; but it is useful in a few cases.

The thing is that a branch is only a shorthand to a tree of commits, just as a tag is a shorthand to a particular commit. Except that when you make commits on a branch, the branch pointer moves along with the latest commit.

There is always the `head` pointer which points at the latest commit, that you have checked out, so you are never really 'disconnected'

Comment: Yep, I now realize this is what I should have done. But are there any times when committing to a detached state is useful?

Answer (score 3):

Committing to a detached head on its own is fairly useless but it is also used during interactive rebasing, which allows you to rewrite the history of a tree, if you mark a commit for editing.

After git reaches such a commit while rebasing it stops the process and you are allowed to change this commit with `git commit --amend` or even insert new commits as you usually do. Most importantly, such commits belong to no branch as `git status` clearly shows, so you commit to a detached head.

Many Git users, me included, think that interactive rebasing is one of the more useful git features and it wouldn't work if committing to a detached HEAD was impossible.